# How to cast double-pointers of a base class to double-pointer of derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast, double-pointer

If I pass a double-pointer to a class or function how can I cast it to either a double-pointer of a derived type or a reference to a pointer of a derived type so that I can access its members?

```
class A
{

};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void Method() {};
};

A *a_ptr = new B{};

void Function(A *const *a_ptr_ptr)
{
    B *const &b_ptr_ptr = dynamic_cast<B *const>(*a_ptr_ptr);
    b_ptr_ptr->Method();
};

int main()
{
    Function(&a_ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I pass a double-pointer to a class or function how can I cast it to either a double-pointer of a derived type or a reference to a pointer of a derived type

You cannot.

> so that I can access its members?

You don't need a pointer to pointer to access members. What you need is a pointer. You can get that by indirecting through the pointer to pointer. In fact, that is what you're attempting in your example program. The issue with the program is that you cannot dynamic_cast pointers to non-polymorphic types such as `A`. You can fix that either by making `A` polymorphic or by using `static_cast` - at the loss of ability to verify whether the passed pointer actually did point to base of `B`.

Alternatively, instead of casting to a pointer to object, you can indirect through that and cast the reference. Example:

```
assert(a_ptr_ptr && *a_ptr_ptr):
B& b = static_cast<B&>(**a_ptr_ptr);
b.Method();
```